# How to Stop Redirecting to 404 page When page Not found in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to stop redirecting to 404 page when page not found in my next.js app. I just want to show my 404 component without redirecting or changing URL.

Currently, next.js redirecting to 404/ URL.

Is there any ways?

Thanks!

Comment: The behaviour you want is what Next.js already provides: the URL is kept as is but the 404 page content is displayed. Can you provide more details on how your app/page is setup, and how you're making it display the `404` page?

Comment: I am having the same issue. In my case it is caused by a code similar to this one (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/17464#issuecomment-1144124541), which is messing with the router in the _app.js. When I remove it, next.js goes  back to it’s normal behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

The Next.js framework has built-in ways for handling 404, 500, and other errors that may occur on your website. But to add custom layout and styling to those pages, you'll need to create both a `/pages/404.js` and `/pages/_error.js` file.

When one of those errors occur, Next.js will render that page instead of the default page it would otherwise automatically generate.

The `/pages/404.js` file will handle all 404 related errors. And the `/pages/_error.js` file will handle 500 type errors.

here's official documentation [customizing 404](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page)

Comment: But still it will redirect to abc.com/404 right? i want to keep the current url and just want to show 404 component!

Comment: well, there is not such built in way to make that, but you can save visited pages in local storage. then when /pages/404.js reloads grab that latest route that you have visited before 404 and router.push(`/${routeFromLocalstorage}`)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom 404 page in NextJS with creating file in

```
/pages/404.js
```

You can create page for **404** error.
For more Details click [here](https://www.netlify.com/blog/2020/12/08/making-a-custom-404-page-in-next.js/)

Comment: But still it will redirect to abc.com/404 right? i want to keep the current url and just want to show 404 component!

Comment: @SahilGeek It's not possible in NextJS

Comment: @SahilGeek _"But still it will redirect to abc.com/404 right?"_ - no, it shouldn't. Unless you are explicitly redirecting to it somehow.